# Blumentopf & Topfblume - gibt es eine Bezeichnung für "umgedrehte Wörter", die inhaltlich zusammengehören? (und mehr davon?)

Tags: compound

In einer Laune fiel mir auf: [Blumentopf](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Blumentopf) und [Topfblume](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Topfblume) [bestehen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)#Determinativkompositum) aus einem [Bestimmungs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinans_(Wortbildung))- und einem [Grundwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinatum)

- die getauscht das andere Wort ergeben
- und beide inhaltlich zusammengehören. (Für eine Topfblume braucht es einen Blumentopf)

Andere Beispiele:

- Bretterboden und Bodenbrett
- Balkenholz und Holzbalken
- Holzofen und Ofenholz

Ich meine schon belegbare Worte statt (grenzwertiger) Wortschöpfungen:

- Blauhelm und Helmblau - nur ist "Helmblau" keine explizit bekannte Farbe.
- Holzbrett und Bretterholz - ebenfalls grenzwertige Wortschöpfung um das gelagerte Holz nach weiterer Verwendung zu beschreiben (Ofenholz, Bretterholz, Balkenholz, ...)

Daher meine Frage:

- Welche solcher Wortpaare gibt es noch?
- Welche Fachwort gibt es dafür oder ist das so selten, dass es reiner Zufall statt beschreibenswertes "Wortspiel" ist?

Comment: schon für das bekannte Spiel der Wortketten (z. B. Wortspiel - Spieltrieb - Triebtäter - Täterwissen - Wissenschaft  --  die Q ist ein spezialfall davon) kenne ich keinen eigenen Begriff

Comment: Interessant auch vielleicht: Einen der beiden Partner kann man oft wiederum als Bestimmungswort nehmen, das andere nicht: Anzughosenanzug macht keinen Sinn, Hosenanzughose aber schon

Answer (score 2):

Als Sammlung der bisherigen Beiträge (alphabetisch geordnet), Community-Wiki-Antwort: jeder fühle sich frei diese Antwort zu erweitern, einfach editieren.

Vorschläge zur Benennung:

- Wortpalindrom

Beispiele:

- Abendfeier / Feierabend
- Angeberton / Tonangeber
- Anzughose / Hosenanzug
- Arbeiterkind / Kinderarbeiter
- Arbeitslohn / Lohnarbeit
- Arbeitsvertrag / Vertragsarbeit
- Auftragsfertigung / Fertigungsauftrag
- Badegast / Gästebad
- Badewanne / Wannenbad
- Balkenholz / Holzbalken
- Bedarfsgespräch / Gesprächsbedarf
- Bedarfshalt / Haltebedarf
- Blütendolde / Doldenblüte
- Bogenjagd / Jagdbogen
- Borstenschwein / Schweineborste
- Bretterboden / Bodenbrett
- Briefpost / Postbrief
- Brotkasten / Kastenbrot
- Bruderherz / Herzbruder
- Bügeleisen / Eisenbügel
- Bundhose / Hosenbund
- Darstellungsfunktion / Funktionsdarstellung
- Doktorfisch / Fischdoktor
- Druckluft / Luftdruck
- Eisenmeteorit / Meteoriteneisen
- Eisennagel / Nageleisen
- Endzeit / Zeitenende
- Fadenschuss / Schussfaden
- Fensterglas / Glasfenster
- Fettleber / Leberfett
- Flächenland / Landesfläche
- Flaschenpfand / Pfandflasche
- Freizeittag / Tagesfreizeit
- Frauenhaus / Hausfrau
- Funktionsverlust / Verlustfunktion
- Funktionwechsel / Wechselfunktion
- Gasthaus / Hausgast
- Geburtensturz / Sturzgeburt
- Gerichtsverwaltung / Verwaltungsgericht
- Gewölbekeller / Kellergewölbe
- Giftpilz / Pilzgift
- Glasspiegel / Spiegelglas
- Grabhügel / Hügelgrab
- Haftisolation / Isolationshaft
- Henkeltasse / Tassenhenkel
- Himmelsstern / Sternenhimmel
- Hofreiter / Reiterhof
- Holzofen / Ofenholz
- Hosenstoff / Stoffhose
- Hühnersuppe / Suppenhuhn
- Kartenspiel / Spielkarte
- Käsereibe / Reibekäse
- Kerzenwachs / Wachskerze
- Kultopfer / Opferkult
- Leitungsbereich / Bereichsleitung
- Leitungswasser / Wasserleitung
- Listenpreis / Preisliste
- Mustertapete / Tapetenmuster
- Paketpost / Postpaket
- Paarwort / Wortpaar
- Pokalsieger / Siegerpokal
- Rahmenvertrag / Vertragsrahmen
- Regalwand / Wandregal
- Satzzeichen / Zeichensatz
- Schauspiel / Spielschau
- Schrankwand / Wandschrank
- Sockenwolle / Wollsocke
- Trocknertrommel / Trommeltrockner
- Wendezeit / Zeitenwende
- Wortzahl / Zahlwort